# How to intercept Android app Intent with frida?

Tags: android, android-intent, hook, intercept, frida

I am trying to simply log a message into the console when a particular Intent is produced. In particular I am testing with the *K-9 Mail App* which should produce the intent **com.fsck.k9.intent.action.EMAIL_RECEIVED** when a new email is received (documentation [here](https://k9mail.app/documentation/development/intents)). Since I am not very good with frida I have been trying to use the following gist I found [here](https://gist.github.com/bet4it/b62ac2d5bd45b8cb699905fa498baf5e):

```javascript
Java.perform(function () {
   var act = Java.use("android.app.Activity");
   act.getIntent.overload().implementation = function () {
     var intent = this.getIntent()
     var cp = intent.getComponent()
     console.log("Starting " + cp.getPackageName() + "/" + cp.getClassName())
     var ext = intent.getExtras();
     if (ext) {
       var keys = ext.keySet()
       var iterator = keys.iterator()
       while (iterator.hasNext()) {
         var k = iterator.next().toString()
         var v = ext.get(k)
         console.log("\t" + v.getClass().getName())
         console.log("\t" + k + ' : ' + v.toString())
       }
     }
   return intent;
   };
})
```

I'm running this script with the following command:

```bash
frida -U --no-pause -l intentMonitor.js -f com.fsck.k9
```

Using this script I can only log when a particular Activity is created.

Comment: Take a look onto the [Activity lifecycle](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle#alc). It contains the methods and when they are executed. Just select the matching method and hook it.

Comment: You should either hook the function that is producing the intent, or hook the receiver that handles it. If you provide the decompiled code, I can help.